# MySQL - Collate

Tags: mysql, database

When I create a database I am ask to choose Default Collate, when I create a table I am ask to choose Collate. utf8_general_ci or ...latin...? What is the basis to distinguish which one is the right one?

Comment: *_ci is case insensitive, meaning if you do something like `WHERE field like '%abc%', it will match either babc or BaBC.

Comment: Nowadays you usually want utf8, so you can store all sort of scripts, not just the latin alphabet. Make sure your client applications (php, whatever) also uses the same encoding.

Comment: Thank you. What makes you to choose ci or cs? I can not think of any life example for cs..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html) determines the sort order of characters, it is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set. Any given [character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html) always has at least one collation. The end of a collation name **ci**, **cs**, and **bin** means **case insensitive**, **case sensitive** and **binary**, respectively. A binary collation like `utf8_bin` is usually case sensitive, too, because it makes binary string comparisons based on the numerical values of strings.

This means if you want to make case insensitive select queries, where a and A are not different, you should use a collation which ends with ci. If you want to make a case sensitive query, where a and A are different, you should use a collation which ends with cs or bin.

If none is selected, the standard level is applied. There are various levels of collation in MySQL, they can for example be shown by

```
mysql> show variables like '%collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. For the second example it should be 'cs' I think.